# get value of dropdowns using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a form with lots of select elements. On blur of each select element I need to check if the user has selected a value from the dropdown. If he has not selected a value, then that dropdown should be highlighted.

```
$('#test_form .class_dd').blur(function () {
    var input = $('option:selected').val();
    alert($('option:selected').val());
    alert(!($('option:selected').val()));
    input.next('div.error_text').remove();
    input.removeClass('highlight');
    if (!input) {
        input.removeClass('green');
        input.addClass('highlight');
        var $msg = $(this).attr('title');
        input.after('<div class="error_text">' + $msg + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Now if I click on dropdown and don't select a value and goes to next field, alert($('option:selected').val()); gives me empty alert. If I select any value that alert gives me again empty value. So always gives empty alert and it will not be highlighted. But if I use $('#dropdownID').val(); it gives me the value correctly. So how can handle this situation?.

Comment: Try `$('option:selected').val()` instead of `$('option:selected').text()`. `.text()` in your case is always filled.

Comment: I tried that...But that gives me empty alert and true for the second alert

Comment: Wasn't that what you wanted?

Comment: But even if the user selects a value from dropdown, it gives an empty alert..so I am confused

Comment: Than you haven't given the options a value. Your options should look like `<option value="somevalue">sometext</option>`. And for the one that says 'choose any one value' it should be `<option>Choose any one value</option>`. (`.text()` will always be filled, `.val()` not)

Comment: But if I use $('#dropdownID').val(); it gives me the value correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stripped it to the bare minimum so it will be easy to understand.

You should do this:

```
$('select').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 0){
        //not selected
        $(this).addClass('high');
    }
}).change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != 0){
        //selected
        $(this).removeClass('high');
    }
});
```

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/1/).

Not that I added the change trigger because otherwise it would look that the option is still wrong when you have selected one, hope this is the functionality you were aiming for.

Just in case, I am concatenating functions, it is the same as doing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/2/).

Comment: Please tell me if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your reply..I tried ur solution. But when I alert $(this).val(), its always giving me null.. But when I use $('#dropdownID').val(); it alerts me the value correctly..Any idea why it is happening like this?

Comment: Jsfiddle seem to be down, so I'll use codepen for now. Please take a look at this example: http://codepen.io/trufa/pen/fpKmc since `$(this).val()` seems to work correctly. Does it work for you? is that what you meant?